# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I want to build my graphql server app, when i build by webpack 4, i've got this error on a decorator of typeorm :

```
ERROR in ./src/models/user.ts 15:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (15:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { JWT } from './jwt';
| 
> @Entity()
| @Unique(['username'])
| @Unique(['email'])
 @ ./src/server.ts 15:0-37 34:45-49
```

The webpack.config.js is like this :

```
var ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/server.ts',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: '/\.tsx?$/',
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            transpileOnly: true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
};
```

The tsconfig.json is like this :

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "fixtures",
    "tests"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": ["es2016", "esnext.asynciterable"]
  }
}
```

When i compile with tsc, i've not got any error but i've got this error when i launch app by `node dist/server.js` :

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Field, ID, Int, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Could you help me to resolve this bug ?
Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `ts-loader` isn't being used.  I think that's because you've specified the `test` as a string instead of a regular expression.  Try removing the surrounding single quotes.  See the example in [the documentation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/master/README.md#configuration).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But actually after compilation, i've got the same error than i used tsc :
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Field, ID, Int, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Any idea to resolve this error ?

Comment: Why are you using both webpack and tsc?  Anyway, the problem is that you have ES6 module syntax in `dist/server.js`.  Assuming that tsc is actually using your `tsconfig.json` file (e.g., you ran `tsc` or `tsc -p .`, not `tsc src/server.ts`), this shouldn't be happening because your `tsconfig.json` file specifies `"module": "commonjs"`.  If you need more help, please publish a repository that reproduces the problem for you.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, here a [repository](https://github.com/daviddlv/graphql-example) to reproduce this error

Comment: OK, I've got the repository and I've run `npm install`.  Now what command do I need to run to reproduce the error?

Comment: The command to build is : npm run build (or tsc) and the command to run is : npm run serve (or node dist/server.js), it's the serve command where i've got an error, you can launch the command : npm run build-and-serve to reproduce the error. It's necessary to have a postgres database matching the ormconfig.json

Comment: I didn't want to bother setting up postgres (my experience has been that it's a pain), so after I created `ormconfig.json` containing `{"type": "sqlite", "database": "test.sqlite"}` and installed the `sqlite3` driver, `npm run serve` gives me the error, `GraphQLError: Type Query must define one or more fields.`  I'm not sure if I'm getting past your error or you're getting past mine.  Can you please add the file name and stack trace of your error to the question?  That may give me a clue to what's happening.

Comment: I will try to configure this repository with sqlite and I'll let you know when it's ok.
The error is :
https://gist.github.com/daviddlv/5a2d0d67ca175367f76742d22bc18231

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error!  Changing `src/models/**/*.ts` to `dist/models/**/*.js` in `ormconfig.json` fixed it and gave me another error, `DataTypeNotSupportedError: Data type "json" in "User.roles" is not supported by "sqlite" database.`.  Hopefully when you try this change in your environment with the postgres database, you get further.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, it works. I make a last commit to run this server.